# When using select2, the browser displays a password update alert

Tags: jquery-select2

I'm fetching a list from an API using the select2 library and listing the relevant data underneath the search box. However, when I select any of the listed data, my browser (Google Chrome) gives an alert as if I've performed a login and updated my password, prompting me to update the saved password. I haven't been able to resolve this issue in any way. Can you help me with this?

`
$(document).ready(function () {

```
var select = $('#searchProduct');

select.select2({
    selectOnClose: true,
    dropdownParent: $("#newOffer"),
    placeholder: "Seçenekleri arayın...",
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: 'API_URL',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term,
                type: 'public'
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            var groupedData = {};
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                if (!groupedData[item.type]) {
                    groupedData[item.type] = [];
                }
                groupedData[item.type].push({
                    id: item.id,
                    text: item.name
                });
            });

            var resultData = [];
            $.each(groupedData, function (type, items) {
                resultData.push({
                    text: type,
                    children: items
                });
            });

            return {
                results: resultData
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
```

});

`

[Google Chrome Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8Rdc.png)

I've been searching for a solution to this problem for days, but I couldn't find one anywhere.